# jqGrid afterclickPgButtons skip the line where isLeaf non is TRUE?

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I use **jqGrid 4.9.3-pre** - free jqGrid by Oleg.

I use:

- contextmenu
- treegrid
- form Edit
- multiselect: false

**Code**

```
treeGrid:true,
ExpandColumn:'name',
treedatatype:"json",
treeGridModel:"adjacency",
treeReader:{
   level_field: "level",
   parent_id_field: "parent",
   leaf_field: "isLeaf",
   expanded_field: "expanded",
   loaded:true,
},
loadonce: false
```

How to If isLeaf is TRUE skip the line and go to the next line where isLeaf non is TRUE?

Comment: Could you describe the problem more exactly? For example. which version of free jqGrid you use, You wrote about `afterclickPgButtons`. The callback exist in form Edit or form View. What you do? What is your problem: to test that the new row is leaf or to go to the next visible non-leaf? `afterclickPgButtons` don't have any interface for "skipping" some rows, but you can simulate `click` on the same (next or previous) navigation buttons of the form inside of `setTimeout`

Comment: By the way `loaded:true` in `treeReader` is false. `treeReader` provides **the names of properties**. The default value `loaded: "loaded"` is correct. All other properties of `treeReader` have default values. Thus you can skip there. You can remove `loadonce: false`, which ignored for TreeGrid, `treedatatype:"json"` is typically unneeded to. If you have `datatype: "json"` then `treedatatype:"json"` will be automatically. Thus you can remove `treedatatype`, `treeReader` and `loadonce`

Comment: I strictly recommend you to download from [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/releases) and to use the latest 4.13.0 version. The version ` jqGrid 4.9.3-pre` means some dayly build at some unspecified day between the release 4.9.2 and 4.10.0.

Comment: go to the next visible non-leaf

Comment: Thanks, now I will try

Comment: Do you use View or Edit form? Do you use `multiselect: true` or not?

Comment: I use Edit form. multiselect: false

Comment: I see some problems which you can have with navigation buttons in Edit dialog in case of using with TreeGrid, but I still not full understand your configuration. Do you have all tree nodes loaded at the beginning in the grid? Do you have only leafs editable? I will write you the answer which explains the main idea what you can do. You could implement yourself the exact behavior, which you need.

Comment: Oleg, please [http://ru.stackoverflow.com](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498241/jqgrid-afterclickpgbuttons-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-isleaf-true)

Comment: I posted some additional information [here](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/498261/198523)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigation buttons of Edit form have no special interface which could allow to skip some rows, but one can use `onclickPgButtons` to prevent the navigation to the next/previous row and to simulate the click on the same button immediately after that. It's important to understand that jqGrid contains hidden field in the form with the `id="id_g"`, which will be used by form editing as the rowid of the *current* editing row. Thus one can change the value of the hidden field *before* simulation of the `click`.

The corresponding implementation of the `onclickPgButtons` callback could be the following:

```js
onclickPgButtons: function (buttonName, $form, rowid) {
    var $self = $(this),
        iRow = $self.jqGrid("getGridRowById", rowid).rowIndex,
        isLeaf = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "treeReader").leaf_field,
        rows = this.rows,
        nRows = rows.length,
        iInc = buttonName === "next" ? 1 : -1,
        isNextRowVisibleLeaf = function () { // iRow - the current row
            var $nextRow = $(rows[iRow + iInc]),
                rowidNext = $nextRow.attr("id");
            if (rowidNext != null) {
                var nextItem = $self.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowidNext);
                if (nextItem != null && nextItem[isLeaf] && $nextRow.css("display") !== "none") {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        },
        $button = $(buttonName === "next" ? "#nData" : "#pData");

    if (isNextRowVisibleLeaf()) {
        return true; // nothing to do
    }
    // we need to fix the row, which the next row is visible leaf
    while (iRow < nRows && iRow > 0) {
        iRow += iInc;
        if (isNextRowVisibleLeaf()) {
            // set the value of hidden field of the form
            // to the id of the found row and simulate the click
            // on the same navigation button
            $form.find("#id_g").val($(rows[iRow]).attr("id"));
            setTimeout(function () {
                $button.click();
            }, 50);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/LocalAdjacencyTree-editNonLeafs.htm).